# Windows 10 Explorer changes all of its opened windows' folder paths to "This PC" after sleep (?)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

For quite some time already, opened windows of file Explorer sometimes automatically change the current path to "This PC" folder -- presumably, this might be tied to sleep mode or drives momentarily going offline.

The suggested reason is that Explorer sees the drives disconnected (or not fully awaken for a moment) for whatever reason, so it automatically updates all of its current windows to show the core folder it knows: "This PC".

The issue is that the drives do go online, but Explorer still does not revert the paths back to what they were. Thus, I have to manually click on "Back" button in each window, so it would show needed folders once again, which this annoying.

Is there a way to **ban file Explorer from changing the folder on its own**? Even if a folder can not be shown for a moment it should wait for its availability rather than change the current path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change mapped drives to Persistent Connections.

Comment: @John Thanks, but I thought that "mapping" goes for network connections while all of my drives are local. Though, I have a couple of RAID 1 drives: one mainboard's Intel software RAID (bootable) and another as a Microsoft Storage Space Device (just for storage). Do they also have "persistent" settings? If so, where can they be changed?

Comment: If the drives are local, Persistence should not matter.  Investigate why drives are losing connection.

Comment: I understand your frustration but you saying what the explorer should or shouldn't do is opinion.  How long should it wait?  What if the drive never comes back?  Would this frustrate the other 90% of users if the explorer just showed a spinning wheel rather than letting them get to business.  This might not even be a problem with the explorer itself but a third party shell extension or a bad drive causing the behavior.  No offense, but there is a lot to think about when millions (billions?) use your operating system.

Comment: @John As I wrote, the drives go offline due to sleep/energy-saving settings. The problem is that Explorer does not restore the folder it should be showing. How can I ban it from changing folders and force it just to stay and wait for the necessary folder to be available again?